# React Native: using variables in render function from Method

Tags: javascript, react-native, methods, react-props, linechart

My code is supposed to ask the user to choose a range from the calendar modal by pressing **Pick Date Range**. This then goes through an api call in MAIN and retrieves data from GOOGLE. Every thing is working fine, now I want to graph the data, identified as **MyData** in **MAIN**. Data is to be used by my compenent **BPM**. I am having trouble actually using MyData to populate the graph. How do we pass the variable? I am new to React Native... help would be greatly appreciated !

```
import React, { Component , useState} from "react";
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Button, Dimensions} from "react-native";
const screenWidth = Dimensions.get("window").width;
var randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
import { DatePickerModal } from 'react-native-paper-dates'
import {
  LineChart,
  BarChart,
  PieChart,
  ProgressChart,
  ContributionGraph,
  StackedBarChart,
} from "react-native-chart-kit";
import axios from "axios";
import firebase from "firebase";

const BPM=()=>{
  
   const myData= [1,2,4,5,6,7,3];
return(
  <LineChart
      data={{
      title: "Beats per minute",
      withVerticalLabels: true,
      withHorizontalLabels: true,
      datasets: [
        { data: 
          myData
        }
      ]
    }}
    width={screenWidth} // from react-native
    height={220}

    chartConfig={
      chartConfig
    }
    bezier
    style={{
      marginVertical: 8,
      borderRadius: 16
    }}
  />

)

}



export default class ProfileScreen extends Component {

  
  MAIN = async (idToken, accessToken) =>{
    const fit_data= await GFIT(accessToken, idToken)
    UPLOAD_FIT_DATA(accessToken,idToken,fit_data)
    const myData= (FORMAT_FIT_DATA(fit_data))

    }
    render() {

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text> Profile Screen </Text>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 20, fontWeight: "bold" }}>
          Welcome, {this.props.navigation.getParam("username")
          }
        </Text>
        <Button
          title="Update My Dashboard"
          onPress={() =>{this.MAIN(this.props.navigation.state.params.idToken, this.props.navigation.state.params.accessToken)}}
        />
        <Text>
          {myData}

        </Text>
      <Calendar />
        <BPM  />



        <Button
          title="Sign out"
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Login")}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}


 
function FORMAT_FIT_DATA(fit_data){

const {minStartTimeNs, maxEndTimeNs,dataSourceId, point}=fit_data
let myData= [point.length]
for (let i=0; i<point.length;i++)
{
 myData[i]=point[i].value[0].fpVal

}
return(myData)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are going to render the data in the component `BPM`

You could pass the data as `props` to `BPM`

```js
const BPM=(props)=>{

return(
  <LineChart
      data={{
      title: "Beats per minute",
      withVerticalLabels: true,
      withHorizontalLabels: true,
      datasets: [
        { data: 
          props.data
        }
      ]
    }}
    width={screenWidth} // from react-native
    height={220}

    chartConfig={
      chartConfig
    }
    bezier
    style={{
      marginVertical: 8,
      borderRadius: 16
    }}
  />

)

}
```

Im MAIN, we could store `myData` to state of `ProfileScreen` by

```js
this.setState({ myData });
```

And in the `render()` method of `ProfileScreen`

```html
<BPM data={this.state.myData} />
```

Comment: I've tried that, but it tells me that they can't find variable myData. Also, when I write "data={myData}" in my BPM component call, the myData variable in MAIN is still not bold indicating that I'm not actually calling the variable from my render function. This is the problem I'm having and not sure how to fix. I simply can't pass myData from main to render() and then to BPM. Any thoughts ?

Comment: I guess you could store the myData in `MAIN` to state of `ProfileScreen` by `this.setState({ myData });`

then in the render method, `<BPM data={this.state.myData} />`

Comment: thank you, I got it to work ! best of luck brotha/sista !

Comment: I'm a little curious... How do you make it work?